# Angular7 - How i can load state from localStorage with nrgx-store/effects

Tags: angular, local-storage, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

How i can load state from localStorage with nrgx-effects?

When I initialize the application, I call

```
this.store.dispatch(new cartActions.LoadCart());
```

Next, the action CART_LOAD is triggered

**cart.action**

```
export class LoadCart implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_CART;
}

export class LoadCartSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_CART_SUCCESS;

    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}
```

Next, I listen to the effect

```
@Effect()
    loadCart$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(cartActions.LOAD_CART),
        tap(action => {
            return this.CartService.getCart().subscribe(cart => new cartActions.LoadCartSuccess(cart));
        })
    );
```

**cart.service**

```
getCart() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}
```

**Local storage**

```
{products: Array(3), cartTotal: 3, cartCost: 12000}
```

But matter to LOAD_CART_SUCCESS does not reach

[NgRx Store DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q69U2.png)

What I forgot to do is to place localStorage in the store during application initialization?

.

Comment: What does your reducer look like? And why are you using a tap in your effect? Not sure if that would actually work in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The tap operator used in your effect will not dispatch any action, you can use it for logging or forwarding..

To fire an action in an effect you have To use operators like map, switchMap, concatMap...ect in order to return a new action to be dispatched.

Your service CartService does not return observable so you can't subscribe to it.

You can change your effect like this:

```
@Effect() loadCart$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(cartActions.LOAD_CART), map(action => {
const cart = this.CartService.getCart();
return new cartActions.LoadCartSuccess(cart); 
}) );
```

Comment: Did not help: <

Comment: Did you implement a reducer To catch the success action and then update your state?

Comment: And then select the part of the state updated using ngrx sélector To get the data

Comment: Can you Mark share with us your reducer and sélector used in your component ??

Comment: My cart.reducer.ts - https://jsfiddle.net/rg2qL4ne/ ; My cart component - https://jsfiddle.net/s0ogja45/